# Scrolling with CSS

Tags: css, scroll

I have 4 tables that need to scroll, they are set up as follows:

1. Table1(static)
2. Table2(Horizontal Scrolling)
3. Table3(Vertical Scrolling)
4. Table4(Horizontal and Vertical Scrolling)

```
Table1   Table2

Table3   Table4
```

The tricky part of this is that Table 3 and 4 need to keep in sync as this is a listing of data broken out into two tables. Table 2 and 4 are in the same situation.

Any ideas?

No Javascript please as we have a script that works, but it is far too slow to work.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
var tables = new Array();
var headerRowDivs = new Array();
var headerColumnDivs = new Array();
var bodyDivs = new Array();
var widths = new Array();
var heights = new Array();
var borderHorizontals = new Array();
var borderVerticals = new Array();
var tableWidths = new Array();
var tableHeights = new Array();
var arrayCount = 0;
var paddingTop = 0;
var paddingBottom = 0;
var paddingLeft = 0;
var paddingRight = 0;


function ScrollTableAbsoluteSize(table, width, height)
{
    ScrollTable(table, null, null, width, height);
}

function ScrollTableRelativeSize(table, borderHorizontal, borderVertical)
{
    ScrollTable(table, borderHorizontal, borderVertical, null, null);
}

function ScrollTable(table, borderHorizontal, borderVertical, width, height)
{
    var childElement = 0;
    if (table.childNodes[0].tagName == null)
    {
        childElement = 1;
    }

    var cornerDiv = table.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[0].childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement];
    var headerRowDiv = table.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[0].childNodes[(childElement + 1) * 2 - 1].childNodes[childElement];
    var headerColumnDiv = table.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement + 1].childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement];
    var bodyDiv = table.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement + 1].childNodes[(childElement + 1) * 2 - 1].childNodes[childElement];

    tables[arrayCount] = table;
    headerRowDivs[arrayCount] = headerRowDiv;
    headerColumnDivs[arrayCount] = headerColumnDiv;
    bodyDivs[arrayCount] = bodyDiv;
    borderHorizontals[arrayCount] = borderHorizontal;
    borderVerticals[arrayCount] = borderVertical;
    tableWidths[arrayCount] = width;
    tableHeights[arrayCount] = height;
    ResizeCells(table, cornerDiv, headerRowDiv, headerColumnDiv, bodyDiv);  

    widths[arrayCount] = bodyDiv.offsetWidth;
    heights[arrayCount] = bodyDiv.offsetHeight;
    arrayCount++;
    ResizeScrollArea();

    bodyDiv.onscroll = SyncScroll;
    if (borderHorizontal != null)
    {
        window.onresize = ResizeScrollArea;
    }
}

function ResizeScrollArea()
{
    var isIE = true;
    var scrollbarWidth = 17;
    if (!document.all)
    {
        isIE = false;
        scrollbarWidth = 19;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)
    {
        bodyDivs[i].style.overflow = "scroll";
        bodyDivs[i].style.overflowX = "scroll";
        bodyDivs[i].style.overflowY = "scroll";
        var diffWidth = 0;
        var diffHeight = 0;
        var scrollX = true;
        var scrollY = true;

        var columnWidth = headerColumnDivs[i].offsetWidth;
        if (borderHorizontals[i] != null)
        {
            var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth - borderHorizontals[i] - columnWidth;
        }
        else
        {
            var width = tableWidths[i];
        }

        if (width > widths[i])
        {
            width = widths[i];
            bodyDivs[i].style.overflowX = "hidden";
            scrollX = false;
        }

        var columnHeight = headerRowDivs[i].offsetHeight;
        if (borderVerticals[i] != null)
        {
            var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight - borderVerticals[i] - columnHeight;
        }
        else
        {
            var height = tableHeights[i];
        }

        if (height > heights[i])
        {
            height = heights[i];
            bodyDivs[i].style.overflowY = "hidden";
            scrollY = false;
        }

        headerRowDivs[i].style.width = width + "px";
        headerRowDivs[i].style.overflow = "hidden";
        headerColumnDivs[i].style.height = height + "px";
        headerColumnDivs[i].style.overflow = "hidden";
        bodyDivs[i].style.width = width + scrollbarWidth + "px";
        bodyDivs[i].style.height = height + scrollbarWidth + "px";

        if (!scrollX && isIE)
        {
            bodyDivs[i].style.overflowX = "hidden";
            bodyDivs[i].style.height = bodyDivs[i].offsetHeight - scrollbarWidth + "px";
        }
        if (!scrollY && isIE)
        {
            bodyDivs[i].style.overflowY = "hidden";
            bodyDivs[i].style.width = bodyDivs[i].offsetWidth - scrollbarWidth + "px";
        }
        if (!scrollX && !scrollY && !isIE)
        {
            bodyDivs[i].style.overflow = "hidden";
        }
    }
}

function ResizeCells(table, cornerDiv, headerRowDiv, headerColumnDiv, bodyDiv)
{
    var childElement = 0;
    if (table.childNodes[0].tagName == null)
    {
        childElement = 1;
    }

    SetWidth(
        cornerDiv.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement].childNodes[0].childNodes[childElement],
        headerColumnDiv.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement].childNodes[0].childNodes[0]);

    SetHeight(
        cornerDiv.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement].childNodes[0].childNodes[childElement],
        headerRowDiv.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement].childNodes[0].childNodes[childElement]);

    var headerRowColumns = headerRowDiv.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement].childNodes[0].childNodes;
    var bodyColumns = bodyDiv.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement].childNodes[0].childNodes;
    for (i = 0; i < headerRowColumns.length; i++)
    {
        if (headerRowColumns[i].tagName == "TD" || headerRowColumns[i].tagName == "TH")
        {
            SetWidth(
                headerRowColumns[i], 
                bodyColumns[i], 
                i == headerRowColumns.length - 1);
        }
    }

    var headerColumnRows = headerColumnDiv.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement].childNodes;
    var bodyRows = bodyDiv.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement].childNodes;
    for (i = 0; i < headerColumnRows.length; i++)
    {
        if (headerColumnRows[i].tagName == "TR")
        {
            SetHeight(
                headerColumnRows[i].childNodes[0],
                bodyRows[i].childNodes[childElement],
                i == headerColumnRows.length - 1);
        }
    }
}

function SetWidth(element1, element2, isLastColumn)
{
    // alert(element2 + "\n\n" + element2.offsetWidth);
    var diff = paddingLeft + paddingRight;

    if (element1.offsetWidth < element2.offsetWidth)
    {
        element1.childNodes[0].style.width = element2.offsetWidth - diff + "px";
        element2.childNodes[0].style.width = element2.offsetWidth - diff + "px";
    }
    else
    {
        element2.childNodes[0].style.width = element1.offsetWidth - diff + "px";
        element1.childNodes[0].style.width = element1.offsetWidth - diff + "px";
    }
}

function SetHeight(element1, element2, isLastRow)
{
    var diff = paddingTop + paddingBottom;

    if (element1.offsetHeight < element2.offsetHeight)
    {
        element1.childNodes[0].style.height = element2.offsetHeight - diff + "px";
        element2.childNodes[0].style.height = element2.offsetHeight - diff + "px";
    }
    else
    {
        element2.childNodes[0].style.height = element1.offsetHeight - diff + "px";
        element1.childNodes[0].style.height = element1.offsetHeight - diff + "px";
    }
}

function SyncScroll()
{
    for (i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)
    {
        headerRowDivs[i].scrollLeft = bodyDivs[i].scrollLeft;
        headerColumnDivs[i].scrollTop = bodyDivs[i].scrollTop;
    }
}
```

We got the code from [this link.](http://www.cubido.at/Default.aspx?tabid=176&EntryID=8)

I hope this helps.

As it stands, the code is far too bulky to process the amount of data we need to. We have approximately 5000 rows of data per month that needs to be displayed on the page.

Comment: any example file? The question doesn't tell much.

Comment: You can't keep two separate scrolling tables in sync using CSS. You could post your script and perhaps someone here could help optimize it?

Answer (score 2):

If by "need to keep in sync" you mean that when you scroll one of them, the other scrolls too, you can't do this with CSS, because you can't manipulate scroll position using CSS.

And one more thing, have in mind that scrollbar in IE goes inside the element and overlaps 20px of this element (there is a workaround for this), and in all other browsers scrollbar goes outside the element.

Comment: It is doable to a certain extent - but he should provide some html sample.

Comment: +1. You can't 'sync' two scroll positions using CSS. JavaScript would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to set the height of an element and then set overflow:auto (this will give you scroll bars when needed).

Its very hard to get rows of a table to scroll properly. I've been trying with things such as wrapping a table row in a div (or vice versa) and setting a max-height and overflow of that div.

That's the best I can do with out seeing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ResizeCells(table, cornerDiv, headerRowDiv, headerColumnDiv, bodyDiv)
{
    var childElement = 0;
    if (table.childNodes[0].tagName == null)
    {
        childElement = 1;
    }

    SetWidth(
        cornerDiv.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement].childNodes[0].childNodes[childElement],
        headerColumnDiv.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement].childNodes[0].childNodes[0]);

    SetHeight(
        cornerDiv.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement].childNodes[0].childNodes[childElement],
        headerRowDiv.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement].childNodes[0].childNodes[childElement]);

    var headerRowColumns = headerRowDiv.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement].childNodes[0].childNodes;
    var bodyColumns = bodyDiv.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement].childNodes[0].childNodes;
    for (i = 0; i < headerRowColumns.length; i++)
    {
        if (headerRowColumns[i].tagName == "TD" || headerRowColumns[i].tagName == "TH")
        {
            SetWidth(
                headerRowColumns[i], 
                bodyColumns[i], 
                i == headerRowColumns.length - 1);
        }
    }

    var headerColumnRows = headerColumnDiv.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement].childNodes;
    var bodyRows = bodyDiv.childNodes[childElement].childNodes[childElement].childNodes;
    for (i = 0; i < headerColumnRows.length; i++)
    {
        if (headerColumnRows[i].tagName == "TR")
        {
            SetHeight(
                headerColumnRows[i].childNodes[0],
                bodyRows[i].childNodes[childElement],
                i == headerColumnRows.length - 1);
        }
    }
}

function SetWidth(element1, element2, isLastColumn)
{
    // alert(element2 + "\n\n" + element2.offsetWidth);
    var diff = paddingLeft + paddingRight;

    if (element1.offsetWidth < element2.offsetWidth)
    {
        element1.childNodes[0].style.width = element2.offsetWidth - diff + "px";
        element2.childNodes[0].style.width = element2.offsetWidth - diff + "px";
    }
    else
    {
        element2.childNodes[0].style.width = element1.offsetWidth - diff + "px";
        element1.childNodes[0].style.width = element1.offsetWidth - diff + "px";
    }
}

function SetHeight(element1, element2, isLastRow)
{
    var diff = paddingTop + paddingBottom;

    if (element1.offsetHeight < element2.offsetHeight)
    {
        element1.childNodes[0].style.height = element2.offsetHeight - diff + "px";
        element2.childNodes[0].style.height = element2.offsetHeight - diff + "px";
    }
    else
    {
        element2.childNodes[0].style.height = element1.offsetHeight - diff + "px";
        element1.childNodes[0].style.height = element1.offsetHeight - diff + "px";
    }
}

function SyncScroll()
{
    for (i = 0; i < arrayCount; i++)
    {
        headerRowDivs[i].scrollLeft = bodyDivs[i].scrollLeft;
        headerColumnDivs[i].scrollTop = bodyDivs[i].scrollTop;
    }
}
```

I appoligize, this part will not format no matter what I do, sorry about the poor formatting.